# web api http get not found (404) while hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am creating a web api application which works fine on local dev server.

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

But when I deployed it to IIS, it's giving below error,

[image]

My Web config is below,

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: got the issue, i need to add app alias name in url also, http://localhost/AlertDemo/api/alert/getalerts